# Cordova - Error code 1 for command

Tags: cordova

I have a problem when I try to execute this command "cordova emulate android"

[image: cordova emulate android]

Do you have any idea to solve this error?

Comment: Can you post the error in text please ? With the image, a part is missing.

Comment: Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"C:\Users\sabira\Desktop\E-AMBITION\tictacdoc\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\sabira\Desktop\E-AMBITION\tictacdoc\platforms\an
droid\build.gradle -PcdvBuildArch=arm -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"

Comment: Missing the error before ?